# Error connecting to Oracle db from Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, connection

I get an error trying to connect to an Oracle19c database from ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2013 through .NET framework data provider for Oracle.

From where can I download Oracle developer tools for Visual STudio 2013. Please provide link.

Can I connect to Oracle19c database any other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BadImageFormatException. This will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: "Attempt to load oracle client libraries throw BadImageformatexception. thisproblem aqccour when running iin 64bit mode with 32bit oracle client comp installed" But I have installed 64bit oracle client comp